# Using ncurses in conjunction wth execvp

Tags: c, fork, ncurses, execvp

I am writing a shell project in C for a class and I decided I wanted to implement arrow-key command history in the shell as an extra feature.  After calling `initscr()`, everything prints out correctly, but when I call `execvp()` inside of a fork to execute shell commands and display the result on the screen, things get a little wacky.  I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181084/execvp-output-creates-indent-for-ncurses) and learned that to avoid those indents from the execvp output, I can use `reset_shell_mode()` followed by `reset_prog_mode()`.  When I do this, the execvp command prints fine, but `reset_prog_mode()` doesn't seem to work correctly if the execvp command works correctly.  Here is some code that demonstrates the problem area.

```c
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    reset_shell_mode();
    execvp(command, args);
    reset_prog_mode();
    refresh();
    printw("error"); // prints correctly
}
else {
    usleep(1000);
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // status is defined, just not in this snippet
    reset_prog_mode();
    refresh();
    printw("completed"); // never prints - printw is scuffed from this point on.  getstr() works tho.
}
```

I'm almost certain that my problem has everything to do with the fork and where I place `reset_prog_mode()` after successful execvp completion, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You've got one terminal and two processes competing to change the terminal modes (a race).  You might be able to see what's happening by studying output from `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you got your question answered already but I'll respond anyway.

If the call to `execvp` is successful then any code after it won't execute. See the documentation for `execvp` and look for what it does to the process' image space when it is called.

I'm currently coding my own shell and I've gotten it to work by placing my `reset_shell_code` call before my call to `fork` and after my `wait` call. Some odd stuff is happening when I call `execvp` with a `man` or something else that takes over the window but the other commands with simply modify the window work.